# reserve memory for a set of processes

Tags: linux, memory, gui, out-of-memory

How can I reserve some amount of memory for a set of UI processes(window manager, x server, a terminal and a shell) running on my system. I'm tired of having to force a reboot because of some resource heavy program eating up all the memory.

Comment: You can use [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) to limit the resource heavy program memory usage.

Comment: @Ipor Sircar is it possible to include all applications except a few ones in a cgroup?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can create a default rule, and exactly specify the excluded ones. cgroups is very flexible. you can also use many groups with different rules, and hierarchy between groups.

Answer (score 1):

Use cgroups. This is the ultimate solution for resource management

Comment: Yes, while this is very likely the right approach, please edit your answer and explain how to implement it. As it stands, this is just a comment offering a general direction and not an answer giving a solution.